# Powershell - Script not entering for each loop

Tags: shell, loops, powershell, foreach, hashtable

I have a script set to enter a for each loop every-time a file is created. Once in the loop it will move a file to a another folder and if the same file has to be moved 3 times it will move the file to a different table and remove the record of it from the hash table.

My issue is when I run the script it does not do anything that I write inside the for each loop. Only if I write script above it. Can someone please advise?

```
$folder = 'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test\r' # Enter the root path you              want to monitor. 
$Failedfolder = 'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test\r'
$filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here. 
$Files = @{}
$Counter = 1


$folder = 'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test\r' # Enter the root path you              want to monitor. 
$Failedfolder = 'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test\r'
$filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here. 
$Files = @{}
$Counter = 1


# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if         required.                           
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property         @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,     LastWrite'} 

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 


    ForEach ($file in $folder) 
    { 
        $fName = $file.Name

        if (-not $Files.ContainsKey($fName))
        {
            $Files.Add($fName,$Counter)
        }

        if (($Files.ContainsKey($fName)) -and ($Files.Item($fName) -lt 3))
        {
            Move-Item 'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test\r\*.txt'      'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test' -force
            $Files.Set_Item($fName,$Counter++)

        }
        ElseIf (($Files.ContainsKey($fName)) -and ($Files.Item($fName) -eq     3))
        {
            $Files.clear()
            Move-Item 'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\Failed\' $Failedfolder -force
        }
    }
} 

# To stop the monitoring, run the following commands: 
# Unregister-Event FileCreated
```

Comment: What `$file in $folder` suppose to mean?

Comment: you declare the folder variable outside of the scriptblock and dont pass it as an argument so inside the scriptblock `$folder` is empty (same is true for `$counter` and `$Files`). pass it as parameter or declare it inside the scriptblock, also what @AgentK wrote

Comment: Can you post show me what you mean? I am so far not getting a different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, you will have to change the folders back though :)

```
$folder = 'C:\temp\test' # Enter the root path you              want to monitor. 
$filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here. 

# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if         required.                           
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,LastWrite'} 

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
$folder = 'C:\temp\test' # Enter the root path you              want to monitor. 
$Failedfolder = 'C:\temp\test3' 
$Files = @{}
$Counter = 1

ForEach ($file in (gci $folder)) 
{ 
    $fName = $file.Name

    if (-not $Files.ContainsKey($fName))
    {
        $Files.Add($fName,$Counter)
    }

    if (($Files.ContainsKey($fName)) -and ($Files.Item($fName) -lt 3))
    {
        Move-Item $file.Fullname 'C:\Users\jnwankwo\Documents\IUR Test' -force
        $Files.Item($fName) = $Counter++

    }
    ElseIf (($Files.ContainsKey($fName)) -and ($Files.Item($fName) -eq 3))
    {
        $Files.clear()
        Move-Item $file.Fullname $Failedfolder -force
    }
}
}
```

Addition:

To store your Hashtable to a file and re-import it on the next run you can use the following code:

```
#store hashtable to file
$Files.GetEnumerator() | % { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" } | Out-File files_ht.txt

#to import again
$Files = Get-Content files_ht.txt | Convertfrom-StringData
```

This should enable you to have the data from the hashtable persistent

Comment: The hash tableis being recreated everytime and so stopping the foreach loop from ever reaching the elseif. I think it would be better if all the variables and the hash table were global. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: @user3162426 the thing is that you give over the scriptblock once, from then on everytime it gets triggered it runs in its own context. if you need to take over data from one run to the next you need to store it outside of the script, for example in the registry. Powershell variables only last as long as the session they are created in afaik, global or not

Comment: @user3162426 i have added some code that would allow you to store and load the hashtable from a file so you can have it persist through runs. Dont forget to empty the file when you empty the hashtable though or you will run into problems ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have found one thing in your code.

Change **ForEach ($file in $folder)** to **ForEach ($file in (gci $folder))**